# How to generate random numbers the give fixed results using Math.random

Tags: java, math, random, range

I am new in JAVA and I think I have searched all the questions without finding one similar to my question.

I want to generate random numbers that would give back 4 fixed numbers using Math.random(). The numbers that I want to get are: 0, 90. 180 and 270. In other words, I want to 4 numbers with a minimum value of 0 and maximum value of 270 and an increment of 90.

Comment: You only need *one* random number from 0..90, and then add 90 three times?

Comment: @Jongware That won't work, if he gets 1 from 0..90, your algorithm would generate 91, 181, 271.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int rand = ((int)(Math.random()*4)) * 90;
```

Let's break that down. Start with `Math.random()`, returning a random decimal in the range [0,1). (Anything between 0 and 0.999999999..., loosely.)

```
Math.random()*4 //Gives a random decimal between 0 and 4 (excluding 4)
```

Next, let's truncate the decimal.

```
(int)(Math.random()*4) //Truncates the decimal, resulting in a random int: 0, 1, 2, or 3
```

Finally, we'll multiiply by 90.

```
int rand = ((int)(Math.random()*4)) * 90; //0*90=0, 1*90=90, 2*90=180, or 3*90=270
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote or mark this question as answered. Awesome job.

Comment: @AmmarSh: Thanks! You can always mark your own question as answered though - just click the green checkmark by it!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) object and reuse it:

```
   Random r = new java.util.Random();
   ...
   int x = r.nextInt(4)*90;
```